# As3 Text Manipulation - How to say "if charAt == Carriage Return"?

Tags: text, flash-builder, flash-cs5, actionscript-3

I currently have a form that disables a send button based on two textfields. The one field is a message box. I want to have it so that a person can't just put in a bunch of enters and spaces. I currently ahve a check for spaces, but charAt just returns a space :/ Here is what I want it to look like:

```
        _sendComposeBtn.visible = true;

              // if the length of the message is zero, don't let people send it
        if (_messageLength == 0)
        {
            trace("hiding");
            _sendComposeBtn.visible = false;
            _realMessage = false;
        }


        _allSpaces = true;
              // start with allSpaces true. If there is a nonspace (or non-enter character then hide send button                
        for (i = 0; i < _bigMessageTextField.length; i++)
        {
            if (_bigMessageTextField.text.charAt(i) != " " && _bigMessageTextField.text.charAt(i) != (ENTER_CHARACTER))
            {
                trace("not a space");
                _allSpaces = false;
            }
        }

        if (_allSpaces == true)
        {
            _sendComposeBtn.visible = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

```
_bigMessageTextField.text.charAt(i) != String.fromCharCode(13)
```

Comment: @Fans you should accept this answer since it worked for you and is correct.

Comment: I'm not a high enough level. Throw me a few rare candies.